# Typescript: Union Type to Deep Intersection of Optional Values (Difficulty: Level 95+)

Tags: typescript, types

I need to convert a union object type (which could have nested unions) into a ***deep intersection of optional values*** type. Essentially all possible fields would be intersected and would be optional only if it exists on one side of the union - and do this for all nested objects.

*Note: This is not a simple Union to Intersection*

Additional comments inline:

```
type DateOnly = string;
type DayOfWeek = string;
type DayOfMonth = string;

// Input Type:
type DateIntervals_Union = {
    kind: 'weekly';
    weekly: {
        startDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek;
        endDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek;
        startDate: DateOnly;
        endDate?: DateOnly;
    };
} | {
    kind: 'monthly';
    monthly: {
        startDayOfMonth: DayOfMonth;
        endDayOfMonth: DayOfMonth;
        startDate: DateOnly;
        endDate?: DateOnly;
    };
} | {
    kind: 'dates';
    dates: {
        dateRanges: {
            startDate: DateOnly;
            endDate: DateOnly;
        }[];
    };
};

// Expected Type:
type DateIntervals_Optionals = {
    // This becomes a union of it's possible values
    kind: 'weekly' | 'monthly' | 'dates';
    // This becomes a union between the object and undefined
    weekly?: {
        // These are unchanged
        startDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek;
        endDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek;
        startDate: DateOnly;
        endDate?: DateOnly;
    };
    monthly?: {
        startDayOfMonth: DayOfMonth;
        endDayOfMonth: DayOfMonth;
        startDate: DateOnly;
        endDate?: DateOnly;
    };
    dates?: {
        dateRanges: {
            startDate: DateOnly;
            endDate: DateOnly;
        }[];
    };
};

// Input Type:
type Schedule_Union = {
    kind: 'once';
    date: DateOnly;
} | {
    kind: 'recurring';
    schedule: DateIntervals_Union;
};

// Expected Type:
type Schedule_Optionals = {
    // Union of possible values
    kind: 'once' | 'recurring';
    // Union of possible values: date | undefined
    date?: DateOnly;
    // Union of possible values: schedule | undefined
    // But the same union => optional type conversion is applied in this nested object
    schedule?: {
        kind: 'weekly' | 'monthly' | 'dates';
        weekly?: {
            startDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek;
            endDayOfWeek: DayOfWeek;
            startDate: DateOnly;
            endDate?: DateOnly;
        };
        monthly?: {
            startDayOfMonth: DayOfMonth;
            endDayOfMonth: DayOfMonth;
            startDate: DateOnly;
            endDate?: DateOnly;
        };
        dates?: {
            dateRanges: {
                startDate: DateOnly;
                endDate: DateOnly;
            }[];
        };
    }
};

// Simple UnionToIntersection does not work:
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
type Schedule_UnionToIntersection = UnionToIntersection<Schedule_Union>;
type Schedule_UnionToIntersection_Actual = {
    kind: 'once';
    date: DateOnly;
} & {
    kind: 'recurring';
    schedule: DateIntervals_Union;
};

// Partial<UnionToIntersection> does not work:
type PartialUnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? Partial<I> : never;
type Schedule_PartialUnionToIntersection = PartialUnionToIntersection<Schedule_Union>;
type Schedule_PartialUnionToIntersection_Actual = {
    kind?: undefined;
    date?: string | undefined;
    schedule?: {
        kind: 'weekly';
        weekly: {
            startDayOfWeek: string;
            endDayOfWeek: string;
            startDate: string;
            endDate?: string | undefined;
        };
        // Not nested
    } | {
        kind: 'monthly';
        // Um.. no, that's not right - where did that even come from?
        weekly: {
            // Bonus points if you can figure out how to make vscode show the full type information
            //...;
        };
    } | {
        //...;
    } | undefined;
};
```

---

#### (Updated: 2020-02-17)

### Purpose

This allows for a more straightforward pattern for extracting data:

```
// BAD: This is not nice when needing to extract a single value
const funWith_unions = (dateIntervals_union: DateIntervals_Union) => {
    // If won't be null eventually :P
    let startDate: string = null as unknown as string;
    if (dateIntervals_union.kind === 'dates') {
        startDate = dateIntervals_union.dates.dateRanges[0]?.startDate;
    } else if (dateIntervals_union.kind === 'monthly') {
        startDate = dateIntervals_union.monthly.startDate;
    } else {
        startDate = dateIntervals_union.weekly.startDate;
    }
    if (!startDate) { throw new Error('No start date'); }
}

// GOOD: Quick, simple, and safe
const funWith_wide = (dateIntervals_wide: Widen<DateIntervals_Union>) => {
    // All possible cases handled in a single statement
    const startDate = dateIntervals_wide.dates?.dateRanges[0].startDate
        ?? dateIntervals_wide.monthly?.startDate
        ?? dateIntervals_wide.weekly?.startDate
        ?? (() => { throw new Error('No start date'); })()
}

// The above uses the excellent code from @jcalz (the accepted answer):

type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type OptionalKeys<T> = T extends any ?
    { [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never }[keyof T] : never;
type Idx<T, K extends PropertyKey, D = never> =
    T extends any ? K extends keyof T ? T[K] : D : never;
type PartialKeys<T, K extends keyof T> =
    Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>> extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;
type Widen<T> =
    [T] extends [Array<infer E>] ? { [K in keyof T]: Widen<T[K]> } :
    [T] extends [object] ? PartialKeys<
        { [K in AllKeys<T>]: Widen<Idx<T, K>> },
        Exclude<AllKeys<T>, keyof T> | OptionalKeys<T>
    > :
    T;
```

Comment: Presumably you want `kind: 'monthly';  weekly: {...` to be `kind: 'monthly'; monthly: {...` instead

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71281937/242684

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I'm going to call what you're doing `Widen` for want of a nicer name that isn't incredibly long.  If I understand correctly, one way of thinking of what you're doing is to take a union of object types and assume that if a property is not present in the *declared* type of a member of the union, that it is actually absent (specifically, an optional property of type `never` or `undefined`).

So a type like `{foo: string, baz: true} | {bar: number, baz: false}` could be thought of as `{foo: string, bar?: never, baz: true} | {foo?: never, bar: number, baz: false}`.  Then what you want to do is *merge* those into a single type with the usual rule where you take the union of each property, and each property is optional if and only if it's optional in at least one of the members of the union, like: `{foo?: string, bar?: number, baz: boolean}`.

And you do this recursively down through object types.

Here's one way I might try to write this.  I'll mention what I'm doing but not necessarily 
the nitty-gritty on how it works because this could be ten pages of text otherwise:

First let's define a type `AllKeys<T>` which distributes `keyof` across unions so `AllKeys<{a: string} | {b: number}>` is `"a" | "b"`:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
```

Then we write a type `OptionalKeys<T>` identifies just the optional keys in a type (and it also distributes across unions), so `OptionalKeys<{a?: string, b: number} | {c: boolean, d?: null}>` should be `"a" | "d"`:

```
type OptionalKeys<T> = T extends any ?
  { [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never }[keyof T] : never;
```

Then let's write a type `Idx<T, K, D>` which looks up the `K` property of type `T`, except that it distributes across unions and if there's no such property it returns the default type `D`.  So, `Idx<{a: string} | {b: number}, "a", 100>` should be `string | 100`:

```
type Idx<T, K extends PropertyKey, D = never> =
  T extends any ? K extends keyof T ? T[K] : D : never;
```

And a type called `PartialKeys<T, K>` which is like `Partial<T>` except it only acts on keys `K` and leaves the other keys in `T` alone.  so `Partial<T, keyof T>` is the same as `Partial<T>`, and `Partial<T, never>` is the same as `T`:

```
type PartialKeys<T, K extends keyof T> =
  Omit<T, K> & Partial<Pick<T, K>> extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never;
```

And *finally* here's `Widen<T>`:

```
type Widen<T> =
  [T] extends [Array<infer E>] ? { [K in keyof T]: Widen<T[K]> } :
  [T] extends [object] ? PartialKeys<
    { [K in AllKeys<T>]: Widen<Idx<T, K>> },
    Exclude<AllKeys<T>, keyof T> | OptionalKeys<T>
  > :
  T;
```

We special-case arrays because mapping over arrays is [treated specially by the compiler](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), and otherwise we only map over object types and not primitives (you don't want to see what happens when you map over `string`, for example).  But the general plan is: get the union of all properties mentioned anywhere in `T`, and make them optional if they are optional or missing in any element of `T`. It might not function perfectly on types that are unions of object *and* non-object types, but I think it does the right thing for your example.

Let's see:

```
type WidenedScheduleUnion = Widen<Schedule_Union>
/* type WidenedScheduleUnion = {
    kind: "once" | "recurring";
    date?: string | undefined;
    schedule?: {
        kind: "weekly" | "monthly" | "dates";
        weekly?: {
            startDayOfWeek: string;
            endDayOfWeek: string;
            startDate: string;
            endDate?: string | undefined;
        } | undefined;
        monthly?: {
            ...;
        } | undefined;
        dates?: {
            ...;
        } | undefined;
    } | undefined;
} */
```

This looks right, except for that `...` because the type is too long.  Let's look those up to see more details:

```
type Monthly = NonNullable<WidenedScheduleUnion['schedule']>['monthly']
/* type Monthly = {
    startDate: string;
    startDayOfMonth: string;
    endDayOfMonth: string;
    endDate?: string | undefined;
} | undefined */

type Dates = NonNullable<WidenedScheduleUnion['schedule']>['dates']
/* type Dates = {
    dateRanges: {
        startDate: string;
        endDate: string;
    }[];
} | undefined */
```

That's what you wanted, right?  Okay, hope that helps you proceed.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwNIRAZwB4AVAPigF4oioIAPYCFAEzyjRRCgH4BYAKChQA3lADaWKAhRQA1riQAzKgF0AtFwBcwgL416jFlAAKCAMYziAGihYyXG1C0oIANwgAnKNtFyQilY5Qzm7uANz8-KCQUACSTLRWDnQMzKxG7kiQ7qA4INYAIhRBrh5k5PyC1MkGrOyc9hLVqbLyStT2ROLKgYVOJWERfFHQAIIY2LiEpEVV+s113C1+bYHBHuF8keDQRmjZCJi5U9aNc4a+-tPlArAAtgjAibZQAGTGe4iYBCbmTyRkTUMUgUHlgixEoiMkmkFyUMGUWhgkO6uj6IQ2W2iAHUEExGMQyhUxERuoDWKIRu53GgQARgaCAKIkbr2CESKRLS4IqA4vEoYhdMioomiEl6FKGURIABGACsIKZgCz3vtDpMCETBGzoVAxhN8ATubz8XEEkQTv8vJZNVAGbRTBgAK54gh6o4E6ywqhkAA+sHgyHQ+qmJCJZA0RKIGM2McGAHoAFRJ5Mp1OpqAJuOY6D5NAMGAoDCcSh4YDuKQAcw2wyguZAMAUWIgEBkRVL5ZQVeztZpDYAsqhgAALNtlyvRuNx2IoMCO4BUbYRobbHsMGIoBjuFyYPAAfQAqihA0UhESZFImFoAOQAd2bMiLV42gjvLaLWlPN0EpY+dYbTZbLQ-0be9n0EGhmGAgCZCA3sQJbMDv2AX88wgWD80LEBEIgphcwYTRVwgAsizA7QNl0P1P0Ec9mGvW5ByHR8wPojdGJAD8bR-bJgIHVjYPrBReOHbCDB4hj+P7BjsK44A8LQwjiKwm1RNQgi5MU0jyKgSizwva8mFQvAnyJAyGDwDivygUyIAAJXYCsIHM4QbSQlCGHQojMOwwQVPchSvJtbxlE0-gyIqfhJ2nWd5yIRduwAZVMIcICYR0MAgA8j1QE9dNoqAr1QUwIGMm5rI8jTQu05ybhoy98vcBVHSpSsSu-JKUrS+S5PXTdtwwPdD0DcjoxrY1nCYRLktS9LBuyygxoISaOvSzLA1DPhEygUbcUYFKlumiBZukSgqPA2qtAAIkKiALqqi6GtMJqOwrC7sOsgj20rKrHWYCAFCkFLpPag6CNO8Czr0qALtfB8QFuv0LpY4ci3hqHrLwV6XPAmGi1BrHwdc7i4OgrRPs7byCZ8yDifvUmx3J-GCZkuS6eeinKd8iAPvpitvt+-7xvZrw+bxAXAcZpG2LxyzKcEAA6BWhYoqAftFgGmCF9HpdlgmFblpWRb+9XsOV1WjcFyrM0GGshLYooADlUHttKMDQaV0oIMa9uBzqjtEK88B99Kr2UEh-clx9lAihMtpXW2ixyyzmdQ1nx045CiYE23U4ZyyVKz8SoDJrs8+p-Cc95v0zbFjXKqr-n1YzLMYxrOTWEoR2UGd8Y3Y9r2JqDw6spQf3A6mzqQ7Dq90ZD6PY+iNvE-B6y7M7RyLJ15O-OLoXOYrk3RGCuuVYb8am6AA)

Comment: Awesome @jcalz this is very helpful!

Comment: what is the purpose of using the array wrapping in the `extends` statements: `[T] extends [...]` instead of just `T extends ...`

Comment: I added an example of how this solves a complicated coding pattern around discriminated unions. Thanks again!

Comment: If you use `T extends ...` with a "naked type parameter", it becomes a [distributive conditional type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) where `T` will be broken into its union constituents, mapped separately, and then joined back together into a new union.  This is often desirable behavior; when it's not, you need to "clothe" the parameter somehow.  The tersest way to do so is `[T] extends [...]`.

Comment: Great answer, great breakdown along the way!