# Implement interface in a way that when a class implements it, it **must** implement all properties of the interface either as optional or not optional

Tags: typescript

I want to implement interface in a way that when a class implements it, it **must** implement all properties of the interface either as optional or not optional.

If I have

```
interface Person {
  name: string,
  address?: string,
}



class Fisherman implements Person {
  name: string;
  fishingRodColor: string;
  // and any more properties I want
}
```

Typescript won't raise an error, it's okay `Fisherman` doesn't implement `address` because it's optional, but I do want it to raise an error, I want it to force me to write `Fisherman` class as one of those two choices:

```
class Fisherman implements Person {
  name: string;
  address?: string;
  fishingRodColor: string;
  // and any more properties I want
}
```

or

```
class Fisherman implements Person {
  name: string;
  address: string;
  fishingRodColor: string;
  // and any more properties I want
}
```

both should be allowed, and at least one of those implementation should be required.

If I simply write my `Person` interface as such with `address` not being optional

```
interface Person {
  name: string,
  address: string,
}
```

It will not allow me to write this class which I want it to allow me:

```
class Fisherman implements Person {
  name: string;
  address?: string;
  fishingRodColor: string;
  // and any more properties I want
}
```

Because it will say `address` can't be optional since it isn't optional in `Person` interface.

**Edit:** I appreciate the help, but another need I have with the solution is that for my use-case, In the case where `address` is optional, I would like to be able to declare this `const` object:

```
const fisherman: Fisherman: {
  name: 'George'
  fishingRodColor: 'Red'
}
```

But if `address: string | undefined`, typescript will still raise an error saying `fisherman` must have the property `address`. Typescript wants me to do this:

```
const fisherman: Fisherman: {
  name: 'George'
  fishingRodColor: 'Red'
  address: undefined
}
```

But I don't want (and I think I also can't in new Mongo versions since undefined was deprecated) to push a field with undefined in it into my database.

I can do workarounds like deleting `undefineds` before inserting into DB, but it probably makes using the interface not worth it for this use-case.

Answer (score 4):

You could transform all optional properties with type `T` to `T | undefined` with:

```
type Complete<T> = {
    [P in keyof Required<T>]: Pick<T, P> extends Required<Pick<T, P>> ? T[P] : (T[P] | undefined);
}
```

See https://medium.com/terria/typescript-transforming-optional-properties-to-required-properties-that-may-be-undefined-7482cb4e1585

In your example:

```
class FishermanError implements Complete<Person> {
  name: string;
  fishingRodColor: string;
  // error: Property 'address' is missing
}

class Fisherman implements Complete<Person> {
  name: string;
  fishingRodColor: string;
  address: string
  // ok 
}

class Fisherman2 implements Complete<Person> {
  name: string;
  fishingRodColor: string;
  address: string | undefined
  // ok  
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyIcAthAFzIZhSgDmANEcnACbtQQYYD81WvRDMCAXwIEwATwAOKAMJYysgDYRIAHgAqAPmQBefK2IBtVMlDIA1hGlYYyAEoQAjgFdg3djt0BdalRgBGsdJjR9CAAPSBB2DGc3T29NIJCwiP0%20ZG1zP2RqAApc1HyAH2R3OIgYUAh2AEoAbnFJBFU4XmQAMWAMAAtoMjgQAFEoKCwoSxV1CnAEpVmNCFTMHH1CYlIKQTpGFuJagcYnLHYlVSm94QZD5AB6B%20RoSahAyfkoGWQAcg4uDwML9LAkyH0MIxWgR2p0Er0BkMRjM1BB5mBFspUVp0FBsCBNqwdlQaPsRPdjv1TudLtdSbd7gDuLwboxiMhobCugjBlBhiAAEwouYQBbIJbY1a4-GE7bkElCA6sSnUi5YK7velK4hMoGskTICpVdg1OrsYicnC0ZCOIwgCAAdx6fV5-MKzRhVrANqFdsdzsRfJGAvdLSAA)

Comment: Oh that's so much more elegant than my version of the same (basic) thing. `Pick<T, P> extends Required<Pick<T, P>>` is **really** clever.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Added the source of `Complete<T>` to give credit where credit is due

Comment: Can you please help me how to force class implement optional properties?

`interface Person {`
`  name: string,`
`  address?: string,`
`}`
`class Fisherman implements Complete<Person> {`
`  name: string;`
`  address?: string;`
`}`
`// Property 'address' is optional in type 'Fisherman' but required in type 'Complete<Person>'.`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do *exactly* what you've said you want to do, but you can get close: You can require that `address` be declared, but if the original is `address?: string`, you'll end up having to declare it as `address: string | undefined` or `address: string` (not `address?: string`). That's not quite the same thing as the property *not being there* although they're mostly (but not entirely) treated the same way. (That said note that TypeScript recently got a [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) related to this.)

(**Edit:** Lesiak has [a much more concise version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69895794/157247) of the below with clever use of `Pick` and `Required` from [this article](https://medium.com/terria/typescript-transforming-optional-properties-to-required-properties-that-may-be-undefined-7482cb4e1585).)

The way I can see to get there uses two utility types and a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with remapped modifiers. The utility types (I got `OptionalKeys` from [this answer by jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118644/157247), then modified it to get `RequiredKeys`):

```typescript
type OptionalKeys<T> = T extends any
    ?   {
            [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never;
        }[keyof T]
    : never;
type RequiredKeys<T> = T extends any
    ?   {
            [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? never : K;
        }[keyof T]
    : never;
```

Those let us figure out which keys are optional and which are required. Then we can use a mapped type (well, a pair of them combined) to change `addres?: string` to `address: string | undefined`:

```typescript
type NoOptional<T extends object> =
    {
        [key in RequiredKeys<T>]: T[key];
    } &
    {
        [key in OptionalKeys<T>]-?: T[key] | undefined;
//  Removes the optionality −−−−^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^−−− adds `undefined` to
//                                                        the property type
    };
```

Then we get an error here as desired:

```typescript
class BadFisherman implements NoOptional<Person> { // Error as desired
    name: string;
    fishingRodColor: string;
    // and any more properties I want
    constructor() {
        this.name = "";
        this.fishingRodColor = "";
    }
}
```

but this works:

```typescript
class GoodFisherman1 implements NoOptional<Person> {
    name: string;
    fishingRodColor: string;
    address: string | undefined;
    // and any more properties I want
    constructor() {
        this.name = "";
        this.fishingRodColor = "";
    }
}
```

and this works:

```typescript
class GoodFisherman2 implements NoOptional<Person> {
    name: string;
    fishingRodColor: string;
    address: string;
    // and any more properties I want
    constructor() {
        this.name = "";
        this.fishingRodColor = "";
        this.address = "";
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMqciHALYQBcyGYUoA5gDTFnJwAm3UEGDAH46DJiDbEAvsWJgAngAcUAeUVhgOOABsA0hHkYAPABUAfMgC8yE8ggAPSCG4YuIeRzJCyhEp3+kANq6yKDIANYGWDA2ALoAtCL4UnaOEM6uqMAI4aasyLoW3iF0IBAAbtAA3J4BUoGR8tFxtcilFdVySigAShAAjgCuwPzc+oamFta2Dk4ubh5+pN6kvgEBwaG4jc0mCUl4KbPp81k5eQVF5B1QbQU1S-71OzF7re2VUA9dysgAclg1BotNpTKk5q4sAAjABWEAQYCmrTW6waBi2yD6QxGEDGBmM5lidBMaPksQenBSADJka1OKSMUDNBQ9PjJvtiaTYsgAD7IQbOCAwUC4ilkKTfIgIbRwQTIABCPAAYsAMAALaCUOC4YCURTaCDUcCuAFMkFGdBQbAgCx4ZAAentyAAolAoFhbrLkNwBDjuK0KNRRIwWGLSML1SwelhuABhLDaD3B8TMMMOp3a7gLZCUD0oRTu5RQDQCZAASWQAHdtWBWggcGJBgiPQAKACU+DpZDAatVADpAyhrAAiYdpzg9-sR3sSaNxhMeqzIUdpmRENfEaWy1wAcSwMZV6s12oAjKE9QajWATYD1MydBbMDhbQGqLR6CGJGnp1GY-HE1Ayahq0PB8AIGBARIvL8oKwplNwaaOm4WbavIOZ5sgBZYEWJauBW1bgHWDaME2YCth2KIBJOGADm+S4rl2pDUX2P6zn+C63COY6tGuG5SjKcp7geqoalAWogAATOe+qGuk17-LewIso+VrPp2jyDpBqatKxzBzv+SYfimaagfwghaYhGbONmub8JhhbQLh5ZVjWREgI2zZQO26nrMgzGDvR3GPBOvY0bp+kcYF47dqFfameBUU8dIQA)

Comment: I ended up with very similar solution. It also worth mentioning about `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` flag