# In TypeScript, how can I require a subclass to implement static method?

Tags: typescript, static-methods, abstract-methods

In TypeScript, I want a given subclass to implement a static method which would be called by the superclass. This method returns data that is really a property of the class and not of an instance and thus makes sense as static rather than non-static from a modeling point of view.

What I'm currently doing in the superclass to call the static method defined in the subclass is this:

```
const r = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.staticMethod()
```

First question: is there a better way to do this? In particular, `constructor` returns `any`, which I never like.

Second: how can I ensure at compile-time that the subclass will implement the static method `staticMethod`? I've tried various approaches, including stuff with `satisfies` like

```
type SuperclassStatic = { someMethod(): number }
const Subclass = class extends Superclass { ... } satisfies SuperclassStatic
```

… but not only does this seem to be invalid syntax in TypeScript 4.9.5, it is also not great that I'd have to remember to add the `satisfies SuperclassStatic` part in every subclass declaration.

Any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First question: is there a better way to do this?

If this is within an *instance* method of the superclass (which you've confirmed in a comment it is), then while you don't have to use `Object.getPrototypeOf`, you are sadly stuck with `this.constructor`, which as you say isn't ideal as its type is just `Function`:

```typescript
const ctor = this.constructor as /*...appropriate type, see below...*/;
// Belt-and-braces runtime check
if (!ctor.staticMethod) { // Slightly surprising TypeScript doesn't say this will never be true, but handy
    throw new Error(`Invalid subclass, has no staticMethod static method`);
}
ctor.staticMethod();
```

(Note: The `!ctor.staticMethod` check above only makes sense in conjunction with another change I make below [making the parent class use a different name for the static method than subclasses]. If you don't make that change, you might do `if (ctor.staticMethod === Parent.staticMethod) {` instead for the condition of that `if` that will throw on an invalid subclass.)

> how can I ensure at compile-time that the subclass will implement the static method staticMethod?

I don't think you can if the names are the same, but if you make the names different it's possible with the help of a do-nothing function so we can use a generic to do the check (here I've made the superclass method's name `parentStaticMethod`, with the subclasses expected to implement `staticMethod`):

```typescript
type Constructor = new (...args: any[]) => any;
type RequiredSubclassMethods = { staticMethod: (...args: any[]) => any };

class Parent {
    static parentStaticMethod() {
        console.log("Parent.parentStaticMethod()");
    }

    method() {
        const ctor = this.constructor as Constructor & RequiredSubclassMethods;
        // Belt-and-braces runtime check
        if (!ctor.staticMethod) { // Slightly surprising TypeScript doesn't say this will never be true, but handy
            throw new Error(`Invalid subclass, has no staticMethod static method`);
        }
        ctor.staticMethod();
    }

    static validSub<Cls extends Constructor & RequiredSubclassMethods>(cls: Cls): Cls {
        return cls;
    }
}

// Works
const GoodSub = Parent.validSub(
    class GoodSub extends Parent {
        static staticMethod() {
            console.log("GoodSub.staticMethod()");
            super.parentStaticMethod();
        }
    }
);

// Fails, doesn't have `staticMethod`
const BadSub = Parent.validSub(
    class BadSub extends Parent {
    }
);

// Calls `GoodSub.staticMethod`()` via `Parent.prototype.method`
new GoodSub().method();
// Fails, doesn't have `staticMethod`
const BadSub = Parent.validSub(
    class BadSub extends Parent {
    //    ^^^^^^ Argument of type 'typeof BadSub' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Constructor & RequiredSubclassMethods'.
    //           Property 'staticMethod' is missing in type 'typeof BadSub' but required in type 'RequiredSubclassMethods'.(2345)
    }
);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-mUpUyWZAajqBommaQ9jy0DNIwAoZE2A5IkHQSBUE6LIekzfpChzJM83RcZE1EckADEaEVJB9RFMVJSgE11SgV1CyjV1d12H4aGfQhPwvK8bzvCpAysb5uJPV9GyiLDvxXEjyRgH1q2Y6Cbzg-942KV1iwUGhmL4zprRwCQ6jjQp2LtR8YNvHhKDMuYRiAA)

`validSub` doesn't have to be a method on `Parent`, but it seemed a reasonable place to put it. It could be a standalone function instead.

Of course, using that `Parent.validSub` is a pain and easily forgotten. :-| I thought we might be able to use `implements` instead of a function (similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69895794/157247)), but if so, I can't get it to work, and in any case it would also (as you say) be a pain and easily forgotten.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Quick question for `super`: I'm using `Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor` from the body of a *non-static* instance method of the *superclass*. It seems your answer is referring to calling a static method of the superclass from the subclass, no?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet - Sorry, I misread that. Yes, of course, you're right that it wouldn't apply there. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Great, thanks! This seems like a decent way to go, until we get stuff like `static` members on interfaces.