# Proper way to use const-asserted arrays of objects with optional fields in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have data like this:

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, a: "foo" },
  { id: 2 },
] as const;
```

I can "validate" it against an existing type:

```
type Row = {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly a?: string;
};

// This will explode if data has { b: "bar" }
const dataValidated: Readonly<Row[]> = data;
```

But I get "Property 'a' does not exist on type ..." when I try to access it:

```
data.map((x) => x.a);
//                ^ Error here
```

And if I use `dataValidated` instead, I lose the type-narrowing of `as const`:

```
dataValidated.map((x) => x.id);
//                         ^^
// number, but I want 1 | 2

dataValidated.map((x) => x.a);
//                         ^
// string | undefined, but I want "foo" | undefined
```

I've tried a naive intersection, and it helped with `id`, but not `a`:

```
const dataIntersected: Readonly<(Row & typeof data[number])[]> = data;

dataIntersected.map((x) => x.id);
//                           ^^
// Good, it's 1 | 2 now

dataIntersected.map((x) => x.a);
//                           ^
// Still string | undefined
```

How can I access all fields without type-widening or altering the data (e.g. adding redundant `a: undefined` to the second item)?

Related: [Typescript: Union Type to Deep Intersection of Optional Values (Difficulty: Level 95+)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60114191/242684)

Answer (score 1):

[Mapped types!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

```
const dataSolved: {
  [K in keyof Row]: Extract<
    typeof data[number],
    Pick<Row, K>
  >[K]
} = data;

dataSolved.map((x) => x.id);
//                      ^^
// 1 | 2

dataSolved.map((x) => x.a);
//                      ^
// "foo" | undefined
```

`{ [K in keyof Row]: ... }` iterates through all fields of `Row` one-by-one, with the key of the field "assigned" to `K`.

`typeof data[number]` is just a union of all literal row types, which is identical to `data` in this case.

`Pick<Row, K>` throws away all fields from `Row` except for `K`, so for `K = 'a'` the result is `{ readonly a?: string }`.

`Extract` throws away all types from the union mentioned above that **don't** match `Pick<Row, K>`, so for `K = 'a'` the result is `{ id: 1, a: "foo" }`.

The `[K]` after `Extract` creates a union of the field `K` common across the union returned by `Extract`, so for `K = 'a'` it's `"foo"`.

The `readonly` and `| undefined` / "optionality" remain there, the mapping doesn't touch them by default.

This is a basic example, for sake of brevity. The solution is a bit more involved for nested structures, but is still possible with [recursive conditional types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#recursive-conditional-types) and [distributivity](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | null | undefined;

type Combine<T extends U, U> = T extends Readonly<Primitive | Primitive[]>
  ? T
  : T extends ReadonlyArray<infer I>
  ? Readonly<Combine<I, Extract<U, Readonly<any[]>>[number]>[]>
  : U extends Readonly<Primitive | any[]>
  ? never
  : string extends keyof U
  ? { [K in keyof T & string]: Combine<T[K], U[K]> }
  : number extends keyof U
  ? { [K in keyof T & number]: Combine<T[K], U[K]> }
  : symbol extends keyof U
  ? { [K in keyof T & symbol]: Combine<T[K], U[K]> }
  : { [K in keyof U]: Combine<T[K], U[K]> };

const combined: Combine<typeof data, Readonly<Row[]>> = data;
```

Somewhat related to the question, it's also possible to make all partially-present fields optional, without a "schema" of the data (no `Row` needed), with [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
type WithKey<T, K extends keyof T> = Extract<T, { [_ in K]: any }>[K];

type OptionalizeHelper<T> = [T] extends [Readonly<Primitive | Primitive[]>]
  ? T
  : [T] extends [ReadonlyArray<infer I>]
  ? Readonly<Optionalize<I>[]>
  : {
      [K in AllKeys<T> as K extends keyof T ? K : never]: Optionalize<
        WithKey<T, K>
      >;
    } & {
      [K in AllKeys<T> as K extends keyof T ? never : K]?: Optionalize<
        WithKey<T, K>
      >;
    };

type Optionalize<T> =
  | OptionalizeHelper<Extract<T, Readonly<Primitive | Primitive[]>>>
  | OptionalizeHelper<Extract<T, Readonly<any[]>>>
  | OptionalizeHelper<Exclude<T, Readonly<Primitive | any[]>>>;

const optionalized: Optionalize<typeof data> = data;
```

I've created a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaB7FgGwgENCnr32TKoQAmEAGYJCEEQG4AUKEhQAggIDSEELgA8AFQB8UHHqgQAHsAijcUHiCgB+KAGstLcVFMAuShExwCkrQAOqoABaaIPoANFDqZpbWIrZuIB5eRjgAopZwXADGwLFQAN5QANoA+lBS8QC6vvZQAL4GFer1Corg0ADyYGgshFzsCABeEAASEOyQcPpZlXr1iVY2lQBK3CLD7NHwyKgY0BSHKGiYFfUG9fJQTl73UL4VK2vJthXbXLuE+yo4PlolJxAwoABJW7PZw-P77HQDIYjMaTHRQ64GZ6+UrPB4PDq1XhqdhRXSGOy2BIWdYpVzuTymZwJXzSAKNKBIhDDUYTCA6PH4h5hYCRLQldRYoUPAwKIUtKAAMjKgoJCTqJLJi0p8Q+GzSGSZfgCLwajl8XJ5qP5qvxIrF0T0cUlttlgpa3WCnMG3JRfO1WGeFEtfsmMzmDB0uQIhWKTqgcL2B0QFxOTHOxyuNwMUqYId5Ydm8yjeVjJUT-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-D4GMB6goQHDYlwNcGPiCTCOMBQaPYUw5TEBD+OvUK4RwwAFKTTB0yQDO1MzUOuFTLMtAAlOTgpIHD2zNXAIg6LzxBxKTboPC01zyKOzWEPgiSQEUfXKDgsQGBzXBnnEtBnmLxhGKUhM63rY39QQAByNC-Rz5hNEOYu+OYtS2ErfDU3bzzBBkgdYDHUAAERK3H5AUJHnjR7Hcek3H3RO0lIj5T9OAVMDtS4wADHEFtQGXrQxCXYO+NNVu+HH2UsEnLR1w85QN1Ai1xAUOLRY3rS1-XuOzXEECvItqyd+PvgACxxOIvizWP3el74ACsK8t7QXBwB3XdlFvUAAGx76fTNQIvo-z5vvcAOxxOEry7-HB-jHHcQ9745+tDnifHuuMAAcr9Xh-ygC-VwvhQGAI3qfXu804jsBbgUHgiUoBUFwNAVAx8F5QGmhXKASAh6EF8CgqALBG41wVPPVYXBbC5y8j5bIQI0oD0wUlQoBRYq2B+pIWYIgUrhAQAUcIQcEpJTqP4BgDgOrJXkPnbaYVvpgA5t7W2WAjDmDClwMWrDS5Bz8qTXyKsWBJV8jXCg00mCLSYBFMKvl5AcxUT9JhUAPpfQMWorgGitF2ygHosGhjiqlR+mNUxYcKDCDEJIaQIhzGUEsX5Gx2DRASBnEk1x7idTPg5t476oFqarGVKnaKBcSn43qBLG4Ys-EaOeIEnRfkAAkpQQkiBaL4DpeiuAtBcWE+QudqE+itHyXG+ZrQ6Aqe4pY7iFCjOas5XGkl3xzILnEIpXAFkF26BYA2wAjb8nSXYigDiKDrwoHfCg28mAAIoE-Jg8CKDzSYMQs2zxAoNmtCICoZd6hhTBifFZpkZAAqBWDeQYTDkQENr0HQ6S4lZMSWbH5vpGz-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) which demonstrates the usage of both `Combine` and `Optionalize`, with type tests.

The `Widen` type from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118644/242684) I found later is very close to `Optionalize`, but doesn't handle tuples and arrays well.