# How to get type of nested union in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am using graphql codegen which generated this type for me:

```
export type GetOffersForMembershipQuery = {
  __typename?: "Query";
  offers:
    | { __typename?: "BaseError" }
    | {
        __typename?: "QueryOffersSuccess";
        data: Array<{
          __typename?: "Offer";
          title: string;
          details: string;
          identifier: string;
          merchant?: {
            __typename?: "Merchant";
            logoImageUrl?: string | null;
          } | null;
        }>;
      }
    | { __typename?: "ValidationError" };
};
```

I want to extract the type of `data` here. How can I do this?

I tried doing simply:

```
GetOffersForMembershipQuery["offers"]["data"];
```

But of course the issue is that `["data"]` doesn't exist if the `__typename` is not `"QueryOffersSuccess"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Extract` to pull just the members out of a union that extends a type.

```
type MyData =
  Extract<GetOffersForMembershipQuery['offers'], { data: unknown }>['data']
```

The [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) is documented as:

```
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never
// Extract from T those types that are assignable to U
```

So in this case, it extracts all members that assignable to `{ data: unknown }`, which in this case is the one member with the `data` property, which makes it safe to access that property.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiwYHkBmPhQDOAYtALLAC2ARgYQBYCWYAigK4GJwC8cA3gCg4cAPoikKAHYBDSsAD8ALjgAidpxUBuIXAh46incIA+-UeOTAZcpaoBC0wsACiUKNBVwAvkbinBwoGBYhJWsgrKahxQiLj4RADKbADGycCEhFq+QQAm0jDSygCCbtKIADwBQdUhltYRqnEEWdXVMIwwADbAyoQwUIySAObarbmY0oydhL39gyPZ1Yw5Vu04jASzA8OjY8JyUMn00pIwtlV7wrVS4bYqFIfHpy2Xwp0QQxAAkpTSQ8AAVSgnVsfW2Qz8cEkbE6nV2ey8kOhsPh1S8AD5UcIfEF-OZQvU7gA1aSdZb5RgQSSudxQTxebQMgQCUJwMiIAAi+WkPDgzhA-WkyRg5Qw2H0RFIUAoNDoTFY0UQAG0AOR6eKEFUAXQANGY8gVlGxJABrSQQADukm86NVBuk2oEAHonYEAHryIA)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I started fiddling, and I wonder if this does what you need?

```js
type test = GetOffersForMembershipQuery['offers'] extends { __typename: infer U } ? U : never
type t2 = test['data']
```

**Original Answer**

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118644/3450914) has everything you need. I started playing around with `NonNullable<T>` to get it working, but that's for retrieving *optional* types, and while it works with nesting when chained, this still shows an error:

```
type Response = NonNullable<NonNullable<GetOffersForMembershipQuery["offers"]>["data"]>;
```

The reason that still isn't quite enough, is that your type is also a *Union*. However I did some looking for you, and I think the link I shared contains all the needed parts.